# update not working

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE dwh.product_in_offer AS t 
SET (t.PRODUCT_BUCKET_TYPE_CODE,t.PRODUCT_BUCKET_TYPE_DESC,t.LAST_EDIT_TYPE,t.CREATE_ID,t.UPDATE_ID) = 
    (SELECT s.PRODUCT_BUCKET_TYPE_CODE, s.PRODUCT_BUCKET_TYPE_DESC, s.LAST_EDIT_TYPE, s.CREATE_ID, s.UPDATE_ID
     FROM dwh.product_in_offer_vw AS s
     WHERE create_id = 0
        AND t.PRODUCT_KEY = s.PRODUCT_KEY 
        AND t.OFFER_KEY=s.OFFER_KEY) 
INNER JOIN dwh.product_in_offer_vw p on t.PRODUCT_KEY=p.PRODUCT_KEY and t.OFFER_KEY=p.OFFER_KEY
WHERE  create_id = 0;
```

> ERROR:Syntax error near INNER, offset 386 "..ND t.OFFER_KEY=s.OFFER_KEY) -->INNER<--"

Any idea ??

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The `INNER JOIN` clause has to go before the `SET` clause.

```
UPDATE dwh.product_in_offer AS t 
INNER JOIN dwh.product_in_offer_vw p on t.PRODUCT_KEY=p.PRODUCT_KEY and t.OFFER_KEY=p.OFFER_KEY
SET (t.PRODUCT_BUCKET_TYPE_CODE,t.PRODUCT_BUCKET_TYPE_DESC,t.LAST_EDIT_TYPE,t.CREATE_ID,t.UPDATE_ID) = 
    (SELECT s.PRODUCT_BUCKET_TYPE_CODE, s.PRODUCT_BUCKET_TYPE_DESC, s.LAST_EDIT_TYPE, s.CREATE_ID, s.UPDATE_ID
     FROM dwh.product_in_offer_vw AS s
     WHERE create_id = 0
        AND t.PRODUCT_KEY = s.PRODUCT_KEY 
        AND t.OFFER_KEY=s.OFFER_KEY) 
WHERE  create_id = 0;
```